# If statement is null how do we return or carry onto other code to be input

Tags: javascript

```
var rateOfPay = Number(prompt("Enter your hourly rate of pay", " ")); 
var workHours = Number(prompt("Enter hours worked", " "));

if (rateOfPay === " " || rateOfPay === null); 
{
    alert("Please enter your Hourly rate \in Dollars");
    console.log(rateOfPay);
}
else
{
}
```

I'm trying to setup this calculation so that it will ask the user for 2 var to be entered:

1. rateOfPay
2. hoursWroked

I want to check for null inputs or 0  and prompt user to re enter those variables `if == null or 0`. How would I go about setting this up?

this is the code that was accomplished based on the input of comments and reading of beginner js book

```
        var rateOfPay, workHours, payCheck; 

     if ( !(rateOfPay > 0) ){

  rateOfPay = prompt("ENTER YOUR HOURLY PAY", " "); 
  console.log(rateOfPay);
     }

if ( !(workHours > 0) ){

    workHours = prompt("ENTER HOW MANY HOURS YOU WORKED", " ");
    console.log(rateOfPay); 
}
```

Comment: You're converting them to numbers, you can use a `do... while` loop for example to ask for input until the input entered is valid.

Comment: Plus your if condition is terminated with `;`

Comment: If one of the answers below worked for you, you should accept the one that did. It awards both you and the one you accept reputation, unlocking more areas of the site for you. It's also polite :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way to handle this...

```
var rateOfPay, workHours;
while ( !(rateOfPay>0) ) { 
 rateOfPay = Number(prompt("Enter your hourly rate of pay", " ")); 
}

while ( !(workHours>0) ) {
 workHours = Number(prompt("Enter hours worked", " "));
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U4K2L/)**

Now, I didn't add a lot of error checking here, basically checking for a number over zero.   Obviously, you can tweak as needed.   What this code does is ask each question over and over until a valid response it entered.

Comment: Yep, "quick and dirty"… (+1)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, this proved to help me the most in the situation. I know that there are probably many ways to achieve this desired goal, however, your input proved to be very influential in obtaining my results and completing my task thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
do
{
     // your code here...
     // your else needs a break to exit do loop
     else
     {
        //...
        break;
     }
}
while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and edited some things,
when you said if rateOfPay is equal to " " or null, well it can't be because the var type is a number if theirs nothing in the prompt page then it will return 0, if their is text in it, it will return 0. So to fix this i just took out

```
if (rateOfPay === " " || rateOfPay === null);
```

and changed it to

```
if (rateOfPay === 0) {
```

I hope this fixes your problem!
heres the final:

```
   var rateOfPay = Number(prompt("Enter your hourly rate of pay", "")); 
   var workHours = Number(prompt("Enter hours worked", ""));

   if (rateOfPay === 0) {
    alert("Please enter your Hourly rate in Dollars");
    console.log(rateOfPay);

   } else {
     console.log(rateOfPay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you also want to clarify that the input was invalid:

```
var rateOfPay;
var workHours;

while (True) {
    rateOfPay = Number(prompt("Enter your hourly rate of pay", " "));
    if (rateOfPay == 0 || rateOfPay === null){
        alert("Invalid rate of pay. Please enter a non-zero number");
    } else {break;}
}

while (True) {
    workHours = Number(prompt("Enter hours worked", " "));
    if (workHours == 0 || workHours === null){
        alert("Invalid work hours. Please enter a non-zero number");
    } else {break;}
}
```

I don't know what your specific use case is, but you might want to use different comparisons, especially if you want to rule out negative or alphabetic inputs as well.